# First order differential equation and maximum interval

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to find the maximum interval of existence of the solutions to this equation: $x'= cos (t+x)$. I don't know how to solve it and I was wondering if there's another way to approach this. Thanks.

Comment: What is your attempt?

Comment: I couldn't solve it and I can't think of another way to do it so I haven't really tried much...

Comment: You can try to introduce a new variable $y(t)=t+x(t)$

Answer (score 1):

Following Artem suggestion, the differential equation write $$y'=1+\cos(y)$$ which is separable; from this $$t+c=\tan \left(\frac{y}{2}\right)$$ and so $$y=2 \tan ^{-1}\left(c+t\right)$$ and finally $$x=2 \tan ^{-1}\left(c+t\right)-t$$ For the remaining, I am sure that you will get much better answers than those I could provide.

Answer (score 0):

As Artem hinted, it is possible to solve this differential equation in closed form.  However, if all you want is the maximum interval of existence, it's easy to see without solving that this interval is $(-\infty, \infty)$: the right side is nice (continuous, differentiable in $x$) everywhere, and since $|x'| \le 1$ the solutions can't "escape to infinity" in finite time.